# how to change windows 2016 docker dynamic / ephemeral port range

Tags: amazon-ec2, nat, docker, amazon-vpc, windows-server-2016

So I've been trying to use Windows Server 2016 docker on AWS EC2 and it seems by default when the docker container try to access the internet, it uses an ephemeral port range of 1024 and above?

Is there anyway to make the windows docker use the standard ephemeral (dynamic) port range the host uses?

Edit - the docker container on windows itself do not have an abnormal ephemeral port range. It's the NAT network on the host itself it seems that's sending out on a low range port.

Comment: Do you know how to see or edit this port range?

Comment: Because the requests I'm having coming from the container are coming back on ports in the 700-799 range for some reason.